# Линковка библиотеки C++ c программой написанной на си

Tags: c++, c

Каким образом можно слинваться с библиотекой написанной на [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), с программой написанной на [c](/questions/tagged/c)?

В свою очередь, у меня есть идея описания интерфейса для работы с объектами, но вот что насчет линковки, я понятия не имею. Есть мысли только о динамической загрузке библиотеки.

Comment: Особых действий не требуется, разве нет? Только в хедерах нужно не забыть в начале `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` и в конце `#ifdef __cplusplus } #endif`.

Comment: Так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917952/can-i-use-shared-library-created-in-c-in-a-c-program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать это можно будет только путем разработки С-интерфейса для вашей библиотеки, т.е. набора интерфейсных функций, не использующих специфические свойства языка С++ и объявленных как `extern "C"`.

В общем случае разработка такого интерфейса - нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Вышло как надо, а я думал придется с бубном танцевать =)